# Angular 2 routing adds anchor in IE9

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9, angular2-routing

I have this router:

```
...
import { Router, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
...

const routes:Routes = [
    { path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
    { path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
    ...
]
```

And I navigate using

```
router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

It works pretty fine in all browsers but IE9.

It adds to the current url a #, so if I navigate to `localhost`, it renders the `HomeComponent` ok, but the url is `localhost/#/home`
And if I manually add `localhost/home` it goes to `localhost/home/#/home` and fails

Can't find anything on the GitHub issues (some similar questions but not the same) and I am not able to find the issue by myself. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 9 does not support HTML5 [**pushstate**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) navigation. Angular2 defaults to Hash navigation on IE9

Comment: What should be the workaround? Hash navigation for everyone? Different navigation for IE9?

Comment: Don't support IE9 would be my default answer. But hey, I don't know your situation :) I don't know about a workaround, but one could be that you deal with it on your webserver. Check whether it's IE9 and then add a hash before the url. But perhaps there is a better way. Did you set your Base href to `/`?

Comment: Unfortunately IE9 is mandatory. base ref is correctly set to /

Comment: Then i suggest my former workaround. Orr... throw a tantrum, and say that they are holding back on progress. This will not be the last thing you will encounter using angular with IE9

Comment: Is pushstate navigation a default feature of angular 2+ ? I'm not directly using pushstate functions in my code but I'm experiencing the same problem.